# Ignore UUID mismatch on "svn switch --relocate"

Tags: svn

This question asks roughly what my question is, but is ten years old now:

[How to change subversion working copy UUID?](https://superuser.com/questions/229983/how-to-change-subversion-working-copy-uuid)

We have an old SVN server that has about 10 repositories on it. Because it is old, all but the newest repositories have the same UUID.

I am in the process of replacing it with a new SVN server. To protect against future actual errors trying to switch between repositories, it would seem good to make the UUIDs on all the repositories different at this point if possible.

However, "svn switch --relocate" will then refuse to work to update user's checkouts as they change to the new server because the repository UUIDs are different.

Is there really no way to get this command to ignore the UUID mismatch? - I would rather have people run the command once now on checkouts that are really from effectively the same repository with an option to ignore the error, and then errors are less likely in the future.

The other option is to set the UUIDs on the new repositories to be the same as on the old server, which will solve the problem now, but leave all the repositories with the same UUID forever into the future.

There is a "--ignore-ancestry" option - will this also ignore the UUID check?